# Quickly creating a Map of objects from an Array of objects using a specified object key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of uniform objects:

```
var objects = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "one"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "two"
}];
```

And I'm converting these to a Map by using the `id` property of each object as Map keys:

```
var map = new Map();

objects.forEach(obj => map.set(obj.id, obj));
```

However, I'd like to do the conversion without:

1. having to manually create a new map object myself, and
2. having to manually iterate over the array and calling `set` myself

Additionally, I don't feel I should be making a utility function for this presumably native functionality.

> **Note:** search queries for *js array to map*, or *js convert array to map*, or *js map from array* are all bloated with stone-age-era answers with `Object`, or solutions with a utility function. I'm looking for *the* native approach here.

I.e. I'm looking for the native JavaScript equivalent of mapping an array to a dictionary in C#, for example.

```
var map = list.ToDictionary(item => item.id);
```

This is so straightforward and convenient, yet interestingly enough, there is no `Map.from` in JavaScript (even though there is an `Array.from`).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*I did my research while writing up the question, and I feel I should leave the solution here, as its possible practical applications are many.*

---

> I'm looking for the native JavaScript equivalent of mapping an array to a dictionary in C#

Considering a `Map` can be [constructed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Parameters) with an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) of 2-element arrays, where the first element of each inner array is used as the key, and the second element is used as a value, I believe this is the native JS equivalent, also the shortest:

```
new Map(objects.map(obj => [obj.id, obj]));
```

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x6ysk0tq/)

Comment: Make sure to polyfill Map if you target non-supported browsers. Check [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility) for browser support. It's already used in [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js), which is commonly used along with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).